# Issues with opening browser window in full screen using Selenium WebDriver Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver, rfid

I am currently doing a project where a RFID tag is tapped, and the associated webpage opens on Chrome (using Selenium). I used Selenium because I wanted to ensure that each webpage that was opened would just open on the same tab, so I wouldn't have multiple tabs open at any one time. I am now wanting when the code is run, for all webpages to be opened in full screen mode (without the search bar).

My code is as follows - I am using "driver.fullscreen_window()" as the code to open it fullscreen . Currently the tester Facebook webpage, will start with a maximised full screen, and will immediately turn back into a half screen with the search bar. Therefore, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas. I am a beginner, so any help would be fabulous.

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
    import subprocess
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    
    driver.fullscreen_window()
    
    link1="http://facebook.com.au"
    link2="http://netflix.com.au/"
    link3="http://google.com.au"
    
    
    reader = SimpleMFRC522()
    last_id=None
    
    driver.get(link1)
    
    while True:
        print("Place tag")
        print (id)
        
        id,text=reader.read()
        if last_id == id:
            pass
        
        else:
            if id == 397491194568:
                driver.get(link2)
    
            elif id == 769847466731:
                driver.get(link3)
    
        
        last_id = id
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `driver.fullscreen_window()` try passing `start-maximized` argument to driver options, as following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It unfortunately results in a bunch or errors surrounding not being able to find the chromedriver. Is there a way in terminal to locate the exact location of the chromedriver?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

After launching the URL, make the window as `fullscreen_window()`

```
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get(link1)

driver.fullscreen_window()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

I just tried that, it seems to 1/2 work. 
In that the page will open half screen then fullscreen. Then every time I scan a new RFID tag, the tab will go half screen and then fullscreen. 
Is there a way for all of them to just go fullscreen, without switching between the 2?

Thank you

Comment: Add driver.maximize_window() before launching URL, then try

Comment: Still does not seem to work, it will do the same action as before and list errors as well.